# The error 'int' object is not callable is being thrown when using an array as a parameter of a function

Tags: python

The error is being thrown at the sum1 function. I do not understand what it means by `int object is not callable`. Is it because I am using an array/list instead of a normal parameter?

```
choice = 0 
total = 0
prototal = 0
sum1 =0
pro = 0


with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)


print ("What would you like to do with the numbers?") 
print("Enter 0 for the sum, 1 for the product")
input(choice)

if choice == 0:
  sum1(array)

elif choice == 1:
  pro(array)


def sum1(array):
  for i in range (len(array)):
    total += array[i]
    print ("THE SUM OF NUMBERS IS " + total)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 19, in <module>
    sum1(array)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Apart from the error ([@Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) already got that), your `sum1()` function will never increase `total` because `total` is in the global namespace - you'll have to add `global total` before you start your loop if you want to increase its value.

Comment: It seems like you are writing this code in the style of some other language. If this is true, I recommend that you try to separate python from that language in your mind as it seems that this is interfering with your understanding of how python works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is:

```
sum1 = 0
sum1(array)
```

trying to call an integer (0) like a function doesn't work. You then do the same thing with `pro`.

Second problem: you load `array` as a list of strings. You cannot add a string to an int.

Try instead

```
def load_nums(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return [int(line) for line in inf]

# sum is already a built-in function

def product(nums):
    total = 1
    for n in nums:
        total *= n
    return total

def main():
    nums = load_nums("input.txt")
    while True:
        print("What would you like to do?")
        choice = input("  0: quit, 1: add, 2: multiply  ").strip()
        if choice == "0":
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        elif choice == "1":
            print("Result of adding is", sum(nums))
        elif choice == "2":
            print("Result of multiplying is", product(nums))
        else:
            print("I didn't understand that. Please enter 0, 1, or 2.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete lines

```
sum1 =0
pro = 0
```

as `sum1` and `pro` will be *functions*.

Delete lines

```
total = 0
```

and

```
prototal = 0
```

as they will be used *inside* of function definitions.

Define the function `pro()` in a similar manner as `sum1()`:

```
def pro(array):
  prototal = 1
  for i in range (len(array)):
    prototal *= array[i]
  print ("THE PRODUCT OF NUMBERS IS " + prototal)
```

Note the indent of the `print (...)`: it is the same as `for ...`, because you don't want to use it in in the loop, but only *after the loop will finish.*.

In a similar way correct the indent in your `sum1()` function and put the initialization of the variable `total` into it, so it will be now

```
def sum1(array):
  total = 0
  for i in range (len(array)):
    total += array[i]
  print ("THE SUM OF NUMBERS IS " + total)
```

Move definitions of both your functions `sum1()` and `pro()` - they have been defined `before` you will use them - the best place is near the top.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the previous line:

```
pro(array)
```

`pro` is an integer, not a function.  The parentheses indicate that you're trying to call a function.  You need to write your product routine and call *that*.  Your running-sum and running-product variables should go *inside* the corresponding functions, not in the main program.  Also, note that a running product begins at 1 (multiplicative identity element), not 0 (additive identity element).

Comment: A bit odd asking a question when answering the question? More explicitly, one of the main sources of the problem would be at the top of the script where they are setting sum1 to 0 => `sum1 =0`.

Comment: I know ... not the best wording to lead OP to the right design.  I'll edit this.

Comment: No worries :). Would probably also add that their definition of the method needs to before they try to call it as well.

Comment: @idjaw: right ... but there are only so many problems I'm going to deal with in a single answer.  `RitaH` needs to work through others as a learning exercise.

Comment: @Rita H: that said, you generally put all of your functions at or near the top of the file.  You have to have each function defined before you call it; the current code will fail, because your `sum1` function comes after its call, and the product function doesn't exist.